# Change default project base path in Ansible AWX/Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I want to use a custom project base path. As far as I understand I need to change PROJECTS_ROOT in /etc/awx/settings.py. However, nothing happens when I do... Do I need to do something to manually reload the settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

`PROJECTS_ROOT` is set by default to `/var/lib/awx/projects`.  Make sure you have created your preferred projects path, set it to be owned by the awx user/group and move any existing projects you've created under the default path to your new path.

You'll need to restart httpd and supervisord for the changes in `settings.py` to be reloaded.